# How to iterate over Ninject StandardKernel's configured bindings to debug?

Tags: ninject, ioc-container, autowired

In my Ninject binding module,

```cs
public class CarModule : NinjectModule 
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Kernel.Bind(scanner => scanner.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllClasses()
              .InheritedFrom<ICar>().BindAllInterfaces());

        foreach (var binding in kernel.GetBindings(typeof(ICar)))
        {
           Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] Service bound to [{1}]",
                        binding.Service.Name,
                        binding.Target.GetType().Name));
        }

        // Output looks like: 
        //[ICar] Service bound to [BindingTarget]
        //[ICar] Service bound to [BindingTarget]
        //[ICar] Service bound to [BindingTarget]
    }
}
```

I need a sanity check to see types I've successfully bound to my services.  I'm having trouble accessing the **type names of the bound types**.  Instead of `[BindingTarget]`, I'd like to see `[Mercedes]`, `[Ferrari]`, etc...

**Is there a good and/or common way to do this?**

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am having the same problem, is it possible? The best I could find was in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680303/log-ninject-resolved-dependencies-application-start-up

Comment: @user3141326 your link is the best thing I've seen so far. To answer your question, I've not yet found a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your IocKernel, I d just add a method to GetAll the Instances of a given Type T, and call it back after   Loading your Module:

```
    public static class IocKernel
    {
        private static StandardKernel _kernel;                         

        public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>()
        {
            return _kernel.GetAll<T>();
        }    

        public static void Initialize(params INinjectModule[] modules)
        {
            if (_kernel == null)
            {
                _kernel = new StandardKernel(modules);

                List<ICar> bindingsList= _kernel.GetAll<ICar>().ToList();
                foreach(ICar binding in bindingsList)
                { 
                    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Service bound to [{1}]", binding.GetType().Name)
                }
            }
        }              
    }
```